# I found an old question with wrong answers. Do I answer the old question? Or do I pose the question again with the correct answer?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/730735/266049) from March 2014. It's a year and a half old. In my opinion, the answers are incorrect. I'm curious as to why two others came up with the exact same solution that's different from mine. I would like to either publish the correct answer, or have my error corrected.

I have thought of posting my own solution so that I can see others' opinion of it. But I'm afraid that since the question is so old, no one will see it.

Is it considered proper protocol to pose the question again, along with my solution, and ask for input?

Comment: Well, if you think that you are correct and the others wrong, you should put your answer to that same question, so that people can compare your answer with others.

Comment: When a new answer is posted to a question that question is moved to the front page. No matter how old the question is. This is called "bumping the thread". The point of bumping is exactly that the community gets to re-evaluate the material in that thread. It is relatively widely thought that new answers to old questions should add something that has not been covered already. A different approach, a new angle,...

Comment: I've reworked my solution. The end result is now the same as the other two answers, but my route is different. I think it adds something new, so I'll post it to the old question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm curious as to why three others came up with the exact same your solution :-)

Comment: Yes, well, this has changed from, My answer is right and the others are wrong, to My answer is new and provides a different POV is no righter than the others. :)

Answer (score 3):

Do not post a new copy of the question, even if you link back to the old one, if it is the exact same question. It will be closed as a duplicate. Instead, just post a new answer (this will bump the thread). You can also draw more attention to the question, if you think it needs more attention, with a bounty or by posting the question in chat.

Jyrki's comment sums it up well:

> When a new answer is posted to a question that question is moved to the front page. No matter how old the question is. This is called "bumping the thread". The point of bumping is exactly that the community gets to re-evaluate the material in that thread. It is relatively widely thought that new answers to old questions should add something that has not been covered already. A different approach, a new angle,...